# How to set frame's background in Racket?

Tags: user-interface, racket, user-experience, usability

How to set frame's background in Racket? I want to change the background color of a window (for usability purposes) while still being able to place other controls in that window (and keep them fully functional).

Currently I don't see a possibility for this. I tried adding a canvas and changing its background color (which works for the canvas itself), but the canvas pushes out other controls due to the GUI toolkit's geometry management.

It would be nice also to have a way to change colors of other controls (buttons, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything for frame, but color of [button](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/button_.html), [check-box](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/check-box_.html) or [message](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/message_.html) can be changed, if you use [bitmap](https://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/bitmap_.html) in field *label* in their constructor. You can use some image from your PC or create that bitmap programmatically:

```
(require racket/gui/base)

(define frame (new frame%
                   (label "Example")
                   (width 500)
                   (height 500)))

(define button-bg (make-object bitmap% 100 50))
(define dc (new bitmap-dc% (bitmap button-bg)))

(send dc set-brush "green" 'solid)
(send dc set-pen "black" 3 'solid)
(send dc draw-rectangle 0 0 100 50)
(send dc draw-text "Click Me!" 20 0)

(define b (new button%
               (parent frame)
               (label button-bg)))

(send frame show #t)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I already used this trick, mostly for iconized buttons (via mrlib/bitmap-label library). But it does not solve the main problem of the window backgrounds (and also makes it harder to work with a button as method (get-label) does not return text anymore).

Answer (score 0):

The GUI is cross platform - and some platforms do not support changing the background color.

https://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2012-February/050626.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But the underlying library GUI based on is wxWidgets that seems to support [wxWindow::SetBackgroundColour method](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window.html#a37219df52734626e23401fd83b25d8a0) for all platforms. Besides, if the Racket's reason for not supporting it is honoring an OS's theme, as the referenced mail list implies, then I should ask why my Racket GUI application does not honor my current OS theme, and how to make it obey it?

Comment: Not anymore. https://blog.racket-lang.org/2010/12/rebuilding-rackets-graphics-layer.html